# htaccess redirect IP except with query string exception

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I redirect an IP to my domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^100\.100\.100\.100
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to add an exception where this query string does not redirect to domain:

> index.php?option=com_notify&task=Send_Mail&hash=4dd2c2c208098797546c5bf0a858b185b564cf23

where hash is always changing. Typically I would redirect on query string with `RewriteCond` and match with `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^option=com_notify&task=Send_Mail&hash=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/whatever? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But I'm not sure how I'd add this as an exception. To summarize I want the IP address 100.100.100.100 to redirect to the main site except when you have `100.100.100.100/index.php?option=com_notify&task=Send_Mail&hash=.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use negation in `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^100\.100\.100\.100$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^option=com_notify&task=Send_Mail&hash= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```